# APEX-Select2 works very slowly if the number of records are large

Tags: jquery-select2, oracle-apex

I have a apex report with 2 columns which are linked to Select2 plugin. One column returns aroun 1000 rows and another returns around 10000 rows.

The column which returns 1000 rows works fine with this plugin. But it is very slow, for the column that returns 10000 rows.

what can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: What do you mean by "2 columns which are linked to Select2 plugin" AND "One column returns aroun 1000 rows and another returns around 10000 rows"?

Comment: 2 columns means, I have added 2 seperate columns, just to see the effect of less number of rows and more number of rows . With column that have less number of rows, works quickly, whereas, the column with large number of rows works very slowly. Both the columns are linked to select2 plugin.